# Pyspark Structred Streaming Parse Nested Json

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

My project is, write json to Kafka Topic and read json from kafka topic finally sink a csv. Everything is okey. But some key a nested json. How can i parsed list in json ?

Example Json:

```
{"a": "test", "b": "1234", "c": "temp", "d": [{"test1": "car", "test2": 345}, {"test3": "animal", "test4": 1}], "e": 50000}
```

You can see my code bellow.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0') \
                    .appName('kafka_stream_test')\
                    .getOrCreate()
ordersSchema = StructType() \
        .add("a", StringType()) \
        .add("b", StringType()) \
        .add("c", StringType()) \
        .add("d", StringType())\
        .add("e", StringType())

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "test") \
    .load()\


df_query = df \
    .selectExpr("cast(value as string)") \
    .select(func.from_json(func.col("value").cast("string"),ordersSchema).alias("parsed"))\
    .select("parsed.a","parsed.b","parsed.c","parsed.d","parsed.e","parsed.f")\

df_s = df_query \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime = "1 seconds")\
    .start()


aa = df_query \
    .writeStream \
    .format("csv")\
    .trigger(processingTime = "5 seconds")\
    .option("path", "/var/kafka_stream_test_out/")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/var/kafka_stream_test_out/chk") \
    .start()


df.printSchema()
df_s.awaitTermination()
aa.awaitTermination()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Schema for column "d" is wrong. It needs to be an ArrayType. Please see the equivalent Scala code, you can convert it to Python.

```
    val schema = new StructType().add("a",StringType)
      .add("b",StringType)
      .add("c",StringType)
      .add("d",ArrayType(new StructType().add("test1",StringType).add("test2",StringType)))
      .add("e",StringType)
```

The json has different column names on each row of "d". I am assuming that is a typo and the fields are "test1" and "test2"

Comment: Thank you. I solved but ı have a another problem. The problem is, 

CSV data source does not support array<string> data type.